# How to create an equation in the dplyr::mutate function in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question about using the mutate function in my real world project. My data is as below.

```
group time A_1 A_3 B_1 B_3 C_1 C_3
1     100  7   5   7   3   5   3
1     200  8   4   5   6   1   2
1     300  5   6   8   9   2   1
1     400  3   5   7   8   2   1
2     100  3   5   7   6   3   2
2     200  4   5   6   0   1   4
2     300  3   3   4   5   3   2
2     400  6   5   3   1   3   7
```

I call the data set as dat. I am trying to calculate the difference between the two columns of each A, B or C type, i.e., A_diff = A_1 - A_3, B_diff = B_1 - B_3, C_diff = C_1 - C_3, etc. I have more types than shown here and how many different types are not fixed. So I want to use the code below to make a flexible equation in mutate function.

```
type = c("A", "B", "C")
for(i in type){
    dat = mutate(dat, paste(i, "_diff", sep = "") = paste(i, "_1", sep = "") -  paste(i, "_3", sep = "")  
}
```

However, I received an error message says unexpected '='.

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "dat = mutate(dat, paste(i, "diff", sep = "") ="
```

Please help me make this correct. I also tried cat instead of paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based on `gather` and `spread` to calculate the difference and then `left_join` to the original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -group, -time) %>%
  separate(Column, into = c("Letter", "Number"), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(Number, Value) %>%
  mutate(Diff = `1` - `3`) %>%
  mutate(Letter = paste0(Letter, "_diff")) %>%
  select(-`1`, -`3`) %>%
  spread(Letter, Diff) %>%
  left_join(dat, ., by = c("group", "time"))
dat2
#   group time A_1 A_3 B_1 B_3 C_1 C_3 A_diff B_diff C_diff
# 1     1  100   7   5   7   3   5   3      2      4      2
# 2     1  200   8   4   5   6   1   2      4     -1     -1
# 3     1  300   5   6   8   9   2   1     -1     -1      1
# 4     1  400   3   5   7   8   2   1     -2     -1      1
# 5     2  100   3   5   7   6   3   2     -2      1      1
# 6     2  200   4   5   6   0   1   4     -1      6     -3
# 7     2  300   3   3   4   5   3   2      0     -1      1
# 8     2  400   6   5   3   1   3   7      1      2     -4
```

Or you can use the following `lapply`-based method.

```
re <- lapply(c("A", "B", "C"), function(x){
  dat[[paste0(x, "_1")]] - dat[[paste0(x, "_3")]]
})

names(re) <- paste0(c("A", "B", "C"), "_diff")

dat2 <- cbind(dat, as.data.frame(re))
dat2
#   group time A_1 A_3 B_1 B_3 C_1 C_3 A_diff B_diff C_diff
# 1     1  100   7   5   7   3   5   3      2      4      2
# 2     1  200   8   4   5   6   1   2      4     -1     -1
# 3     1  300   5   6   8   9   2   1     -1     -1      1
# 4     1  400   3   5   7   8   2   1     -2     -1      1
# 5     2  100   3   5   7   6   3   2     -2      1      1
# 6     2  200   4   5   6   0   1   4     -1      6     -3
# 7     2  300   3   3   4   5   3   2      0     -1      1
# 8     2  400   6   5   3   1   3   7      1      2     -4
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "group time A_1 A_3 B_1 B_3 C_1 C_3
1     100  7   5   7   3   5   3
1     200  8   4   5   6   1   2
1     300  5   6   8   9   2   1
1     400  3   5   7   8   2   1
2     100  3   5   7   6   3   2
2     200  4   5   6   0   1   4
2     300  3   3   4   5   3   2
2     400  6   5   3   1   3   7",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data from @www you can also try

```
res <- sapply(seq(3, ncol(dat), 2), function(x, y)  y[x] - y[c(x+1)], dat)
cbind.data.frame(dat, setNames(res, paste0(names(res), "_diff")))
  group time A_1 A_3 B_1 B_3 C_1 C_3 A_1_diff B_1_diff C_1_diff
1     1  100   7   5   7   3   5   3        2        4        2
2     1  200   8   4   5   6   1   2        4       -1       -1
3     1  300   5   6   8   9   2   1       -1       -1        1
4     1  400   3   5   7   8   2   1       -2       -1        1
5     2  100   3   5   7   6   3   2       -2        1        1
6     2  200   4   5   6   0   1   4       -1        6       -3
7     2  300   3   3   4   5   3   2        0       -1        1
8     2  400   6   5   3   1   3   7        1        2       -4
```